# URL String passing two values in one parameter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Right so I have these url string to be passed in ajax request. What i wanted to get is to be able to get both results of Call Manager and Contact Centre.

First Code:

```
urlstring = 'search_field=Category&searchtype=BasicSearch&search_text=Call Manager&';
```

Now I will add Contact Centre in the urlstring same parameter with call manager(**search_text**). I've tried this code:

```
urlstring = 'search_field=Category&searchtype=BasicSearch&search_text=Call Manager&search_text=Contact Centre&';
```

But it only shows Contact Centre in the result. Same if i do something like this:

```
 urlstring = 'search_field=Category&searchtype=BasicSearch&search_text=Contact Centre&search_text=Call Manager&';
```

It will only show Call Manager in the result.

I will then add that url string in another variable so don't worry about the & at the end

```
 urlstring = urlstring + 'parenttab='+p_tab[0].value+ '&';
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: We need to see more code to help. Heard of jsFiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `search_text` as an array by appending `[]` to it: `search_text[]=value1&search_text[]=value2`

Comment: This is must straightforward approach if you want PHP to automatically assemble X number of values for `search_text` into an array in `$_GET['search_text']` (or `$_POST` depending on your usage).

Comment: Try `print_r($_REQUEST['search_text']);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Basically added the '?' to the start of the string (not sure if you've got this somewhere else. If so, just remove from the urlstring), and also removed the & from the end as there are no more variables after this.

urlstring = '?search_field=Category&searchtype=BasicSearch&search_text=Contact Centre&search_text=Call Manager';

Answer (score 1):

Use array in your query string variable(search_text[]) or you can put them in one variable separated by a delimiter for example |.

**Using Array:**

```
...&search_text[]=Call Manager&search_text[]=Contact Centre
```

PHP Code:

```
$search_texts = $_GET["search_text"];
```

The variable $search_texts is an array that contains Call Manager & Contact Centre.

**Using Delimiter**

```
...&search_text=Call Manager|Contact Centre
```

PHP Code:

```
$search_texts = explode("|", $_GET["search_text"]);
```

The variable $search_texts is an array that contains Call Manager & Contact Centre.